# Oracle : Determine if a date is in the present, past or future?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time, compare

I want to write an SQL query that would return 'PAST', 'PRESENT' or 'FUTURE' based on a given date :

Today is `2016-03-25`.

```
SELECT 
    TO_DATE('2016-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
FROM 
    DUAL;
```

This query returns : 727185

So, when I do this :

```
select decode(sign( TO_DATE('2049-03-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') - TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')  ), 
              -1 , 'PAST' , 
               0 , 'PRESENT' ,
                'FUTURE') 
  from dual;
```

I always get `FUTURE`as a result of the query, because the returned number is always > 0.

How can I make this work ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in different ways; the most readable (for me) is something like this:

```
with test(d) as ( select TO_DATE('2016-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual)
select case 
       when trunc(d) = trunc(sysdate) then 'PRESENT'
       when trunc(d) > trunc(sysdate) then 'FUTURE'
       when trunc(d) < trunc(sysdate) then 'PAST'
       end
from test
```

Answer (score -2):

you should use :

```
select decode(sign( TO_DATE('2015-03-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') - CURRENT_DATE  ), 
              -1 , 'PAST' , 
               0 , 'PRESENT' ,
                'FUTURE') 
  from dual;
```

because :

```
select TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual
```

-> result :         3/16/0025
year 0025